# Why are my objects not visible when looking through camera and starting the game

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm trying to make a simple game in Blender, but nothing will render when I try to play the game looking through the camera.
The game looks fine in object mode:

[image: 3D Window]

It looks fine through the camera:

[image: Through the camera]

Rendering a frame looks fine:

[image]

And playing the game looks fine as well:

[image]

But then looking through the camera and playing, or starting the game in player just displays a blank grey screen:

[image]

I've been googling and found a few questions similar to mine, but none of their solutions have worked so far. I've cleared restrict render and checked the clipping on my camera (set end to like 1500) to no effect. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Check if your objects are not disabled from render

Comment: Do you mean the camera icons in the object menu, _Restrict rendering_? I've played with those to no effect, unless you're referring to something else?

Comment: Yes thats one of the reasons that the objects may not show up.

Comment: Your camera may have animation frames, and when you start the game, it's not playing that animation

Comment: Okay, I think I might've fixed it. I had camera parented to the spaceship, and popping it back out again caused the ship to start rendering again. Is it common practice to parent cameras to objects? I'm still very new to blender :D. I'm working on my laptop now, when I get home I'll try applying this fix to my main file and post the results.

Comment: So un-parenting the camera from the object did fix my render issue, but it's still odd because apparently this is common practice in blender and shouldn't cause any issues. I'll post another question with this focus.

Comment: That is odd.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to apply (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) the location of both your camera and the object it's parented to, to get rid of any positioning discrepancies during runtime.